# Formula to get lessor of two date fields before comparing to another third date field?

Tags: formula, formula-field

I am trying to find the lessor of two date fields, then comparing that "lessor" date field to another date field to trigger a checkbox on/off.

Here is the current formula, however, im trying to figure out how to find the lessor of the two date fields (`Actual_Shipment_Date__c and Fulfillment_Date__c`) before comparing it to `Scheduled_Ship_Date__c` in the second nested `OR` statement.

```
IF(
  OR(
    AND(TODAY() > Scheduled_Ship_Date__c, (Line_Status__c = "OPEN")),
    AND(
      OR(
        Actual_Shipment_Date__c > Scheduled_Ship_Date__c,
        Fulfillment_Date__c > Scheduled_Ship_Date__c
      ),
      (Line_Status__c = "CLOSED")
    )
  ),
  True,
  False
)
```

Comment: You can *always* reduce `IF(condition, true, false)` to simply `condition`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson If I reduce it to just a condition and not IF condition, how would that work for both of my OPEN and CLOSED scenarios?  In other words, can I have multiple conditions for a single checkbox without nesting them in an IF condition?  Something to consider, this is for all for one checkbox formula.

Comment: The output of your `OR` is either `true` or `false`, and then your `IF` just outputs exactly the same value. Conversely, if you had `IF(condition, false, true)`, you would simply use `NOT(condition)`.

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/285532/multiple-if-statements-for-formula-checkbox)?

Comment: @DerekF Good point...hehe.  Can this be merged?

Comment: I don't think merging would make any sense at this point, given that you received two quality answers, one of which you accepted, and your current formula appears to be different than what you had there.

Comment: Your logic specific to the text of the question is correct, namely: `OR(Actual_Shipment_Date__c > Scheduled_Ship_Date__c, Fulfillment_Date__c > Scheduled_Ship_Date__c)`

Comment: @AdrianLarson If Actual_Shipment_Date__c is 7/12/19 and Scheduled_Ship_Date__c is 7/12/19 while Fulfillment_Date__c is 7/13/19, the Past_Due checkbox is being checked when it should not be because I want to take the lessor of the two dates ( Actual_Shipment_Date__c and Fulfillment_Date__c) and then compare whichever one is smaller of the two to Scheduled_Ship_Date__c.

Comment: Isn't it just like this?
```IF (
  Actual_Shipment_Date__c > Fulfilment_Date__c,
  Actual_Shipment_Date__c > Scheduled_Ship_Date__c,
  Fulfilment_Date__c > Scheduled_Ship_Date__c
)```

Comment: @HengkyIlawan I wish it was that easy.  Unfortunately, that does not work.  I am thinking I might have to create two separate fields, and perform the lessor of two dates formula in one, and then reference that field name in the other field formula.