# Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '-'. Expected Number, DateTime, received Date?

Tags: formula-field

I am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong in this Salesforce formula.  I am trying to find the MIN between two dates.

```
IF(
  ISBLANK(Fulfillment_Date__c) && ISBLANK(Actual_Shipment_Date__c),
  NULL,
  IF(
    ISBLANK(Fulfillment_Date__c),
    Actual_Shipment_Date__c,
    IF(
      ISBLANK(Actual_Shipment_Date__c),
      Fulfillment_Date__c,
      NOW() - MIN(NOW() - Fulfillment_Date__c, NOW() - Actual_Shipment_Date__c)
    )
  )
)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '-'. Expected Number, DateTime, received Date
```

I don't know why as the `Actual_Shipment_Date__c` and `Fulfillment_Date__c` dates are Date data types.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `NOW()` will return datetime so its better to get the Date using `DATEVALUE()` and then use it.

Comment: use `TODAY()` instead of `NOW()` , now gives date time  type

Comment: @RohitMourya I tried with 'DATEVALUE()' but am getting the following error: Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function DATEVALUE(). Expected 1, received 0

Comment: `DATEVALUE(NOW())` otherwise use `TODAY()`

Comment: @sdandamud1 when I user TODAY(), I get the following error:   Error: Formula result is data type (Date), incompatible with expected data type (true or false).  When I use NOW(), I get the following error:  Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '-'. Expected Number, DateTime, received Date

Answer (score 2):

This error is expected because the operator `-` requires both the operand of same data type. The `NOW()` returns a datetime and other is your date field. Hence its giving you an error.

Solution would be to use either `DATEVALUE(NOW())` or `TODAY()` (as suggested by sdandamud).

Also inner `IF` is not returning anything. `If` should always return `True` or `False`. It should be like this:

```
IF(
      AND (ISBLANK(Actual_Shipment_Date__c),
      Fulfillment_Date__c,
      TODAY() - MIN(TODAY() - Fulfillment_Date__c, TODAY() - Actual_Shipment_Date__c)), true, false
    )
```

Comment: When I use TODAY(), I get the following error:   Error: Formula result is data type (Date), incompatible with expected data type (true or false).

Comment: Yes, that is expected. Its because your whole formula should return either `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Right now its not returning the expected value.

Comment: Oh ok, I see what you mean.  So, can I nest this into another formula, or do I need to create separate formula fields and then reference one.  For example, this is the formula for finding the lesser of two dates right?  However, I have another formula filed for validating true and false conditions.  Can I nest this into that formula?  Here is a link to the other formula:  [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/287879/formula-to-get-lessor-of-two-date-fields-before-comparing-to-another-third-date?noredirect=1#comment432045_287879)

Comment: Yes, you can nest it.

Comment: Rohit, I tried nesting it in my other formula....but same error.

`IF(
  OR(
    AND(TODAY() > Scheduled_Ship_Date__c, (Line_Status__c = "OPEN")),
    AND(
      OR(
        Actual_Shipment_Date__c > Scheduled_Ship_Date__c,
        Fulfillment_Date__c > Scheduled_Ship_Date__c
      ),
      (Line_Status__c = "CLOSED")
    ),
    AND(
      ISBLANK(Actual_Shipment_Date__c),
      Fulfillment_Date__c,
      NOW() - MIN(NOW() - Fulfillment_Date__c, NOW() - Actual_Shipment_Date__c)
    ),
    True,
    False
  )
)`

Comment: @Fadiddy Again you're repeating the same mistake. Both the operands in the inner `if` are not of same type. They both should be of either datetime or date. Refer the updated answer.

Comment: Sorry about that, I meant this:

`IF(
  OR(
    AND(TODAY() > Scheduled_Ship_Date__c, (Line_Status__c = "OPEN")),
    AND(
      OR(
        Actual_Shipment_Date__c > Scheduled_Ship_Date__c,
        Fulfillment_Date__c > Scheduled_Ship_Date__c
      ),
      (Line_Status__c = "CLOSED")
    ),
    AND(
      ISBLANK(Actual_Shipment_Date__c),
      Fulfillment_Date__c,
      TODAY() -
        MIN(TODAY() - Fulfillment_Date__c, TODAY() - Actual_Shipment_Date__c)
    ),
    True,
    False
  )
)`

Comment: @Fadiddy What error are you getting? I suspect the AND condition in the inner if has some problem. There should be ISBLANK check for this field `Fulfillment_Date__c`. If this new error is different then please post as another question.

Comment: Rohit, thank you for your help.  The error I am getting is:

`Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'AND()'. Expected Boolean, received Date`

Comment: Adjust this last part `TODAY() - MIN(TODAY() - Fulfillment_Date__c, TODAY() - Actual_Shipment_Date__c))` in another `if` according to your business logic. This statement is not returning any boolean. Hence you're getting this error.